# How to load mp3 files located on sdcard on android device?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, path, mp3, android-sdcard

With this script, I can load mp3 files from my PC:

```
public string path = C:\Users\PC\Desktop\myMusic.mp3

IEnumerator Start()
{

using (WWW www = new WWW(path))
{
yield return www;

source.clip = www.GetAudioClip();
source.Play();
}
}
```

However, it dosen't work on Android. The mp3 files are located in the MP3 folder in my sd card. I tried with these path:
"/storage/emulated/MP3/myMusic.mp3" ; "/storage/sdcard/MP3/myMusic.mp3" ; "/storage/emulated/sdcard/MP3/myMusic.mp3" but it didn't work.

So, I don't know if I didin't use the correct path or if the WWW.GetAudioClip() method dosen't work on Android.

Sorry for my bad english, I hope you understand. I really need yout help.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the path. You have to use C# `FileInfo` and `DirectoryInfo` API to return the appropriate path then pass that path to the `WWW` API. Pass `/mnt/sdcard` to the `DirectoryInfo` API and it will give you to proper path to use. The path to use with the `WWW` API to access data on the SD-Card is  `"file:///" + FileInfo.FullName.`.

Blow is an example. It assumes that the music *.mp3* files are placed in a folder named *"music"* on the SD card. If it's in a folder named *"MP3"* then change `"/mnt/sdcard/music"` to `"/mnt/sdcard/MP3"` Make sure to go the *Build Settings* for Android, change the **Write Permission** from *Internal* to *External (SDCard)*.

```
public AudioSource aSource;

public string path = @"/mnt/sdcard/music";
private FileInfo[] info;
private DirectoryInfo dir;

IEnumerator LoadAndPlaySound()
{
    //Get the proper path with DirectoryInfo
    dir = new DirectoryInfo(path);
    //Get all .mp3 files in the folder
    info = dir.GetFiles("*.mp3");

    //Use the first audio index found in the directory
    string audioPath = "file:///" + info[0].FullName;

    using (WWW www = new WWW(audioPath))
    {
        yield return www;

        //Set the AudioClip to the loaded one
        aSource.clip = www.GetAudioClip(false, false);
        //Play Audio
        aSource.Play();
    }
}
```

It's a coroutine function so you would call it as `StartCoroutine(LoadAndPlaySound());`

Comment: Thank you so much for your fast and very detailed answer! However, it still doesn't work.. I put this path "/mnt/sdcard/MP3" but I have this error: DirectoryNotFoundException: Directory 'C:\mnt\sdcard\MP3' not found. Is it normal that Unity add a "C:" at the beggining of the path?

Comment: You're supposed to run this on your Android not in the Editor on Windows. That's why you see that error

Comment: I tried and you're right the path is correct on my Android device but nothing is happening. Is mnt/sdcard/... the only path or does it exists different path according to the model of phone?